# CSS Class for Input-Validation Error in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

Are there any classes I can set when input validation failed to highlight the input (red)?

Answer (score 1):

This classes are added to the `ion-input` or `ion-select` element by Ionic:

```
State                          Class if true    Class if false
-----                          -------------    --------------
Control has been visited       ng-touched       ng-untouched
Control's value has changed    ng-dirty         ng-pristine
Control's value is valid       ng-valid         ng-invalid
```

So for instance you can use `ng-touched` and `ng-invalid` to show a error message in that field.